# problem of deleting an element from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Workout class and I want to delete a specific element from the list

```
   class Exercise {
       String name;
       String weight;
       String reps;
       String sets;
      bool isCompleted;
    
      Exercise({
        required this.name,
        required this.weight,
        required this.reps,
        required this.sets,
        this.isCompleted = false,
      });
      void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
      }
       String getName(){
         return this.name;
       }
       void setWeight(String weight){
         this.weight=weight;
       }
       void setReps(String reps){
         this.reps=reps;
       }
       void setSets(String sets){
         this.sets=sets;
       }
    }
```

```
    import 'package:fitness_tracker/models/exercise.dart';
        
    class Workout {
          String name;
    
          final List<Exercise> exercises;
          Workout({required this.name, required this.exercises});
        
          void setWorkoutName(String name) {
            this.name=name;
          }
          String getWorkoutName(){
            return this.name;
          }
        }
```

```
void deleteOneWorkout(String workoutName, int index)async {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < workoutList.length; i++) {
      Workout workout = workoutList[i];
      if (workout.getWorkoutName()==workoutName) {
        if (count == index) {
          print(index);
          workoutList.removeAt(i);
          notifyListeners();
          // Save to database
          db.saveToDatabase(workoutList);
          // Load heat map
          loadHeapMap();
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to print the length of the list and it's still the same length why removeAt is not working?
I add a print statement right before the removeAt line (in the inner if block) to see if the execution actually reached there

if I have in the list "we" at index 0 and "go" at index 1 and "we" at index 2 and if I try to remove the "we" at index 2 nothing is printed if I try to remove "we" at index 0 it is print the i value and remove the element

Comment: Have you verified that the `if` conditions are satisified for `removeAt` to be called?

Comment: I print the value of i inside the if block nothing is printed I don't know why even I try to print the value of i inside the for block it's printed I don't know what is wrong with if block

Comment: No, you should add a print statement right before the `removeAt` line (in the inner if block) to see if the execution actually reached there

Comment: look if I have in the list "we" at index 0 and "go" at index 1 and "we" at index 2 and if I try to remove the "we" at index 2 nothing is printed if I try to remove "we" at index 0 it is print the  i value and remove the element

Comment: Just editing the question to state "the problem is solved" is not the correct way. Ideally you write an answer yourself with the solution. Because now this question serves no purpose at all anymore. It might even be better to delete the question altogether if you are not planning to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understand about your logic code. Why you pass `index` to `deleteOneWorkout` function and what is this purpose of `count` flag?.

*But* if you want to remove object that matched by `workoutName`, You can write like that.

```
void deleteOneWorkout(String workoutName, int index)async {
  for (int i = 0; i < workoutList.length; i++) {
    Workout workout = workoutList[i];
    if (workout.getWorkoutName() == workoutName && index == i) {
        workoutList.removeAt(i);
    }
  }
  print("List ${workoutList.length}");
}
```

Comment: No this won't work for me

Comment: I have many Workout which have the same name under each workout have many exercises

Comment: Let, clarify your need, for list [we,go,we], You want to delete first one or last one or both?

Comment: I want to delete any element that I select

Comment: Watch this video to get an overview of the app: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/noureddin-sameer-45760a236_codealpha-intern-softwaredevelopment-activity-7163317684170809344-9o4T?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_android

Comment: I agree with you that I can rewrite my code like that:                                     
 void deleteOneWorkout(int index) async { workoutList.removeAt(index); notifyListeners(); db.saveToDatabase(workoutList);     loadHeapMap(); }

Comment: But I have many functions depend on the same way that I mentioned in the questionmore complicated

Comment: Unfortunately, No

Comment: @NoureddinSameer I updated my answer, let me know if it oki or not

Comment: Thank you very much, it's s working

Comment: @NoureddinSameer the `count` part is really weird

Comment: Yes, you write count++; in if condition, if this condition is false, count will not increase.

Comment: You are right because if I have a list like[we,go,we] and if I select the second 'we' when i=0 the 'count' will be 0 and index will be 2 after checking the condition count will be 1 and when i=3 the 'count' is equal to 1 and index is equal to 2 so the condition will be false after checking the condition 'count' will equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the deleteExercise function takes the name of the exercise that you want to delete. It then uses the removeWhere method of the list to remove the exercise whose name matches the provided name. This will solve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).